# Reduce an array of nested hashes to a flattened array of key/value pairs

Tags: ruby

Given the following data structure:

```
[
    [:created_at, "07/28/2017"],
    [:valid_record, "true"],
    [:cs_details, { gender: 'm', race: 'w', language: nil } ],
    [:co_details, { description: 'possess', extra: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'} } ]
]
```

I want an array of arrays of key/value pairs:

```
[
        [:created_at, "07/28/2017"],
        [:valid_record, "true"],
        [:gender, 'm'],
        [:race, 'w'],
        [:description, "process"]
        [:a, "a"],
        [:b, "b"],
        [:c, "c"]
]
```

Problem is I don't know how to flatten those hashes. `flatten` doesn't do anything:

```
arr.map(&:flatten)
 => [[:created_at, "07/28/2017"], [:valid_record, "true"], [:cs_details, {:gender=>"m", :race=>"w", :language=>nil}], [:co_details, {:description=>"possess", :extra=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}}]]
```

So I know `flat_map` won't help either. I cannot even turn those hashes to arrays using `to_a`:

```
arr.map(&:to_a)
 => [[:created_at, "07/28/2017"], [:valid_record, "true"], [:cs_details, {:gender=>"m", :race=>"w", :language=>nil}], [:co_details, {:description=>"possess", :extra=>{:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}}]]
```

The problem with the above methods is that they work top level index only. And these hashes are nested in arrays. So I try reduce and then invoke flat_map on result:

```
arr.reduce([]) do |acc, (k,v)|
  if v.is_a?(Hash)
    acc << v.map(&:to_a)
  else
    acc << [k,v]
  end
  acc
end.flat_map(&:to_a)
=> [:created_at, "07/28/2017", :valid_record, "true", [:gender, "m"], [:race, "w"], [:language, nil], [:description, "possess"], [:extra, {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}]]
```

Not quite there, but closer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Will the argument on the right be guaranteed to be either one value or a Hash?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp yes

Comment: Do you want all nested hashes to be arrayed?

Comment: Yes I just want an array of arrays of key/value pairs like I show in the example in my question.

Comment: You will have to write some sort of recursive function.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ do not use `reduce` in such a case, use `each_with_object`, the latter does not re-create an object on each iteration, but modifies it inplace, saving memory and having no penalties on redundant objects instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ flattener = ->(k, v) do
▷   case v
▷   when Enumerable then v.flat_map(&flattener)  
▷   when NilClass then []  
▷   else [k, v]  
▷   end  
▷ end  
#⇒ #<Proc:0x000000032169e0@(pry):26 (lambda)>
▶ input.flat_map(&flattener).each_slice(2).to_a
#⇒ [
#    [:created_at, "07/28/2017"],
#    [:valid_record, "true"],
#    [:gender, "m"],
#    [:race, "w"],
#    [:description, "possess"],
#    [:a, "a"],
#    [:b, "b"],
#    [:c, "c"]
#  ]
```

Comment: Note this works in ruby-2.3.1 but not ruby-2.1.2. The latter will complain about passing flattener to flat_map without arguments

Comment: input.flat_map {|k,v| flattener.call(k,v) }.each_slice(2).to_a in  ruby-2.1.2

Comment: @Donato in Ruby 2.1 `flattener = -> ((k,v))` would work. I am surprised the original version does not, I would consider it being a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from writing a helper function that will be called on each item in the array. So that the results are uniform, we will make sure that this function always returns an array of arrays. In other words, an array containing one or more "entries," depending on whether the thing at index 1 is a hash.

```
def extract_entries((k,v))
  if v.is_a? Hash
    v.to_a
  else
    [[k, v]]
  end
end
```

Trying it out:

```
require 'pp'

pp data.map {|item| extract_entries(item)}
```

Output:

```
[[[:created_at, "07/28/2017"]],
 [[:valid_record, "true"]],
 [[:gender, "m"], [:race, "w"], [:language, nil]],
 [[:description, "possess"], [:extra, {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}]]]
```

---

Now, we can flatten by one level to reach your desired format:

```
pp data.map {|item| extract_entries(item)}.flatten(1)
```

Output:

```
[[:created_at, "07/28/2017"],
 [:valid_record, "true"],
 [:gender, "m"],
 [:race, "w"],
 [:language, nil],
 [:description, "possess"],
 [:extra, {:a=>"a", :b=>"b", :c=>"c"}]]
```

Comment: `:extra` in the last row is associated with a `Hash` which is definitely not intended. I doubt this could be done without recursion.

Comment: I agree. I like your solution that makes use of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_flat(arr)
  arr.flat_map { |k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) ? to_flat(v.compact) : [[k, v]] }
end
```

test

```
arr = [ [:created_at, "07/28/2017"],
        [:valid_record, "true"],
        [:cs_details, { gender: 'm', race: 'w', language: nil } ],
        [:co_details, { description: 'possess', extra: { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'} } ] ]
to_flat(arr)
#=> [[:created_at, "07/28/2017"], [:valid_record, "true"], [:gender, "m"],
#    [:race, "w"], [:description, "possess"], [:a, "a"], [:b, "b"], [:c, "c"]]
```

Comment: `v.class == Hash` is a code smell, unless you are absolutely positive that you want to discard any `Hash` descendants. Use `v.is_a?(Hash)` or `Hash === v` instead.